# Can I use a system wide library in a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have installed [`CHIP_IO`](https://github.com/xtacocorex/CHIP_IO) library according to the instructions in the [README](https://github.com/xtacocorex/CHIP_IO/blob/master/README.rst). I can now use the library (`import CHIP_IO.GPIO as GPIO`) in a script which I run with the system wide Python install (`/usr/bin/python`).

However, when I activate an existing `virtualenv`, I get an error: `ImportError: No module named CHIP_IO.GPI`.

Is there a way for me to use `CHIP_IO` library inside the `virtualenv` environment?

Comment: `--system-site-packages
                        Give the virtual environment access to the global
                        site-packages.`

Comment: @KlausD., can I do that to the existing virtual environment?

Comment: Set a symlink in the `include` folder!